# How to open a file dialogue box from Zend AMF + AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, zend-framework, header

I want to send a request to my Zend AMF to Open a Dialogue Box for a File Download.

The process:

Send a request to the Zend Server from my flash App, process the MYSQL results with PHP, then send the result to the browser as a file download (.csv) AND a result true or false to the app

I have the code working just fine outside of the Zend Environment, but of course, when i go to echo/print the file - it sends back to flash with nothing happening.

Is there any way around this?

```
        $file = "";

        $outtype = "Content-type: application/octet-stream";
        header($outtype);

        $outtype = 'Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"';           
        header($outtype);

        $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $email, $location);

        while($stmt -> fetch()){

            $file .= '"'.addslashes($col1).'"';
            $file .= ',"'.addslashes($col2).'"';
            $file .= ',"'.addslashes($col3).'"';
            $file .= "\n";

        }   

        print $file;
        exit;
```

Or, do i have to just request this outside of the zend request...?

So far i have changed the headers to make use of the zend headers:

```
        $this->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');           
        $this->setHeader('Content-disposition:', 'attachment');
        $this->setHeader('filename:', 'file.csv');
```

But am unsure how to the attach $file to 'file.csv' and then return a result of true to Flash AND download the file.. (zend noob here i am afraid..)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Zend MVC? If so make sure you are not rendering a layout....

I am not too happy with the exit; statement... since zend uses an mvc framework, it builds the response and renders it.  Causing the script to exit might mean the content does not get rendered properly.

Also, make sure you use the correct zend functions to build the headers, it is very possible that zend is adding conflicting headers to the response. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.response.html

Comment: I will have to take a good long look at that. If i am being honest - this a little in the deep end for my skillset, but thanks for putting my in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The process could be :

```
-1 Send a request to Zend Framework
-2 Query Mysql, process the result & write the file to the server
-3 Zip the file
-4 return the file url to Flash
-5 inform the user that the file is ready for download
-6 a user click calls navigateToURL from Flash, using the returned url
```

Since it's a zip file url, the browser should open a dialog box.

According to this excerpt from the docs, it seems that your options are fairly limited, as it's not only a Flash issue...

```
In Flash Player 10 and later running in a browser, using this method 
programmatically to open a pop-up window may not be successful. 
Various browsers (and browser configurations) may block pop-up windows 
at any time; it is not possible to guarantee any pop-up window will appear. 
However, for the best chance of success, use this method to open a 
pop-up window only in code that executes as a direct result 
of a user action (for example, in an event handler for a 
mouse click or key-press event.)
```

Comment: Unfortunately flash doesnt allow spawning of new windows when not directly tied to a mouse event. A frustrating problem when dealing with as3 + zendAMF. Your method would work, but only if after the file url is returned, the user clicks another button. Not an ideal scenario - but does work.

Comment: That's not so bad , you could have an alert box confirming that the file is ready to be downloaded and ask the user whether to proceed or cancel.

Comment: It's not ideal. it's one more click between the user selecting an action - and the result. you wouldnt expect a login to ask you if you realy wanted in, or if you really wanted to download a file. If it were something that didnt require such a specific act i might allow it - but in this case (in an admin panel) you already have logged into the admin, picked the date range - and hit submit. By that point i don't want to get in the way of the user and the action.

Comment: The real question is whether you have the choice... check my edited answer.